# Representation of elements in $H_1(Y)$ by a surface.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $Y$ be a closed 3-manifold. Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are a collections of closed curves with multiplicities. If there there exists an oriented surface with boundary  $\Sigma$ and a smooth map $f:\Sigma \rightarrow [-1,1]\times Y$ such that is a cobordiam from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ I want to prove that the homology class of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equal in $H_1(Y)$.

Any hint would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $M$ is an oriented n+1 dimensional smooth manifold the orientation of $M$ in $H_{n+1}(M,\partial M)$ is mapped by the boundary map in the LES of a pair to the compatible orientation of $H_n(\partial M)$. Suppose $f: M \rightarrow X$ is a map from M into the space $X$ then we have a map of pairs $(M,\partial M) \rightarrow (X,X)$ which induces a square: $H_{n+1}(M,\partial M) \rightarrow H_{n+1}(X,X) \rightarrow H_n(X)$ equals $H_{n+1}(M,\partial M) \rightarrow H_n(\partial M) \rightarrow H_n(X)$

Since the first composite is 0, this means that nullbordant singular manifolds are homologous to 0 which implies your question.

Alternatively, since 2-dimensional manifolds are all simplicial complexes you can sum all of the singular simplices that are pushedforward to give an "explicit" boundary between the two.